# Wordpress: Disable Backend

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running a simple Wordpress Membership website, I have installed my own membership plugin and custom login page, however I'm unable to remove the horrible WP toolbar (also disabling the option in the user profile doesn't work, the bar is still there) I also want to totally strip the backend for the user (subscribers only) and not allow to access their profile page, the dashboar and whatsoever backend element, I don't need to know where a user live, his website and stuff like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place this in your theme's `functions.php` for example.

```
//Disable black bar. It will still be visible in wp-admin
if (current_user_can('subscriber'))
{
    show_admin_bar(false);
}

//Redirect from wp-admin
add_action('admin_init', 'my_admin_redirect');
function my_admin_redirect()
{
    if (!defined('DOING_AJAX'))
    {
        if (current_user_can('subscriber'))
        {
            $refer=wp_get_referer();
            if (!$refer || strpos($refer, 'wp-admin'))
            {
                wp_safe_redirect(home_url());
            }
            else
            {
                wp_safe_redirect($refer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hello, thank you for sharing, does it works for subscribers only?

Comment: @Ritardi.Net don't forget to accept it if it has solved your problem

Comment: thank you! could I also use `some url here` instead home_url()?

Comment: @Ritardi.Net yes, absolutely